# Image Picker is not working in when I try to call Google Place Markers

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, jquery-plugins, picker

So I am using this Image Picker jQuery plugin (http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) to show pictures and the names of Google Places POIs.

I called the jQuery function like below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").imagepicker({
            hide_select: false,
            show_label: true
        })
    });
</script>
```

Then in the JavaScript, I call the createMarkers method to get the POI images and names like below:

```
function createMarker(place) {
        ....

        //get POI photos and descriptions
        var photos = place.photos;
        if (photos) {
            //placesList.innerHTML += '<img src=' + photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 80, 'maxHeight': 80 }) + '>';
            placesList.innerHTML += '<option data-img-src=' + photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 80, 'maxHeight': 80 }) + ' value=' + encodeURI(place.name) + '> ' + place.name + ' </option>';
        };
        if (!photos) {
            //placesList.innerHTML += '<img src="images/POI.png" width="80" height="80">';
            placesList.innerHTML += '<option data-img-src="images/POI.png" value=' + encodeURI(place.name) + '>' + place.name + '</option>';


        };
    }
```

The JavaScript above will result in this HTML:

```
<option data-img-src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4bnhVag9P98/UD6MLNW_EzI/AAAAAABTrV4/H91UaZkqFYg/w80-h80-s1600/Stedelijk%2BMuseum%2BAmsterdam" value="Stedelijk%20Museum"> Stedelijk Museum </option>
```

The problem is, even I have the correct JavaScript and correct HTML result, why the jQuery is not working? Thank you in advance for your precious insights.

Cheers,
Nisa

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of the plugin and I know I'm extremely late. Have you been able to fix this problem?

If you are updating the html dynamically you need to reinitialize the picker. I'd recommend populating the 'select' element first, then calling the picker.